# Definition of sober: does it necessarily include drugs other than alcohol? Which ones?

Tags: meaning, phrases

When I say sober it means “not intoxicated.” And intoxicated would be under the influence of alcohol or any controlled or illegal substance.

Is someone sober if they are alcohol free but, let’s say, “barred out” on Xanax as they say? or what about nodding out on Oxy? tripping balls on LSD?
I know this will have many opinions but logically Xanax is a GABA receptor agonist with a slightly different chemical structure than ethyl alcohol, so right there “sober” must pertain to more than strictly alcohol in my opinion. Thoughts?

Comment: I think this depends on opinion and context. It may also depend on what the law says, if the word is used in a legal context (e.g. in the context of being drunk/intoxicated while driving or operating machinery).

Comment: Words are often used with a range of meanings from the narrow to the broad. There isn't a Magic Book Of English that says what the meaning 'necessarily' is.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the word can be used to indicate that one's capacities (that are relevant to the context) are not diminished by the effects of **any** intoxicating substance, or that they are not diminished by the effects of **the** intoxicating substance that is indicated by the context. The primary meaning of the word, however, is not being under the influence of alcohol: that's what most people will will first think of upon hearing the word outside a context that clearly points to another interpretation.

So, if one wants to use the word in the ways that are suggested in the question, one can, but only if the context makes it clear that this is what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

**Sober** refers to any intoxicating substance.

> abstaining from drinking alcohol or taking intoxicating drugs : refraining from the use of addictive substances (see SUBSTANCE sense 3c)

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sober)

**Intoxication** can be limited to

> the condition of having physical or mental control markedly diminished by the effects of alcohol or drugs

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intoxication)

What constitutes "markedly diminished" is likely to be vary somewhat by opinion.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what counts as an intoxicating drug: there may be a medical definition but dictionary definitions are often very vague e.g. from Google "liable to cause someone to lose control of their faculties or behaviour." Does that include Xanax?

Comment: @StuartF I added details. Pushed hard enough, this becomes primarily opinion based. There is some foundation given by saying "markedly diminished". Certainly LSD is an intoxicant.